# Inconsistencies between latest numpy and scikit-learn versons?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, python-3.7

I just upgraded my versions of numpy and scikit-learn to the latest versions, i.e. numpy-1.16.3 and sklearn-0.21.0 (for Python 3.7). A lot is crashing, e.g. a simple PCA on a numeric matrix will not work anymore. For instance, consider this toy matrix:

```
Xt
Out[3561]: 
matrix([[-0.98200559,  0.80514289,  0.02461868, -1.74564111],
        [ 2.3069239 ,  1.79912014,  1.47062378,  2.52407335],
        [-0.70465054, -1.95163302, -0.67250316, -0.56615338],
        [-0.75764211, -1.03073475,  0.98067997, -2.24648769],
        [-0.2751523 , -0.46869694,  1.7917171 , -3.31407694],
        [-1.52269241,  0.05986123, -1.40287416,  2.57148354],
        [ 1.38349325, -1.30947483,  0.90442436,  2.52055143],
        [-0.4717785 , -1.46032344, -1.50331841,  3.58598692],
        [-0.03124986, -3.52378987,  1.22626145,  1.50521572],
        [-1.01453403, -3.3211243 , -0.00752532,  0.56538522]])
```

Then run PCA on it:

```
import sklearn.decomposition as skd
est2 = skd.PCA(n_components=4)
est2.fit(Xt)
```

This fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3563-1c97b7d5474f>", line 2, in <module>
    est2.fit(Xt)

  File "/home/sven/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 341, in fit
    self._fit(X)

  File "/home/sven/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 407, in _fit
    return self._fit_full(X, n_components)

  File "/home/sven/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 446, in _fit_full
    total_var = explained_variance_.sum()

  File "/home/sven/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 36, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not '_NoValueType'
```

My impression is that numpy has been restructured at a very fundamental level, including single column matrix referencing, such that functions such as np.sum, np.sqrt etc don't behave as they did in older versions.

Does anyone know what the path forward with numpy is and what exactly is going on here?

Comment: It should be est2.fit(Xt) above

Comment: I see that `Xt` is a `numpy.matrix`.  The `matrix` class behaves differently than the regular numpy array object.  Have you tried running your example with a regular numpy array instead of a `numpy.matrix`?

Comment: With the same versions as you (except Py3.6), your code runs just fine.  I'm not aware of any major changes to `numpy` that would give problems, though I don't know much of what the `PCA` is doing.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, the use `np.matrix` isn't the problem.  This code runs for me.  The `_NoValueType` error suggests there may be problem with the relatively (np 1.15) new `initial` parameter for `np.sum`, possibly in an incompatible `scipy` version.

Comment: For what it's worth: I just tried your code with Python 3.7, numpy 1.16.3, scipy 1.2.1 and scikit-learn 0.21.0, and it worked.  This was on a 64 Linux platform.

Comment: *"I just upgraded my versions of numpy and scikit-learn to the latest versions..."* I suspect something went wrong with your upgrade.  How did you install scikit-learn 0.21.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point your code `fit` as run `scipy.linalg.svd` on your `Xt`, and is looking at the  singular values `S`.

```
    self.mean_ = np.mean(X, axis=0)
    X -= self.mean_

    U, S, V = linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
    # flip eigenvectors' sign to enforce deterministic output
    U, V = svd_flip(U, V)

    components_ = V

    # Get variance explained by singular values
    explained_variance_ = (S ** 2) / (n_samples - 1)
    total_var = explained_variance_.sum()
```

In my working case:

```
In [175]: est2.explained_variance_                                              
Out[175]: array([6.12529695, 3.20400543, 1.86208619, 0.11453425])
In [176]: est2.explained_variance_.sum()                                        
Out[176]: 11.305922832602981
```

`np.sum` explains that, as of v 1.15, it takes a `initial` parameter (ref. `ufunc.reduce`).  And the default is `initial=np._NoValue`

```
In [178]: np._NoValue                                                           
Out[178]: <no value>
In [179]: type(np._NoValue)                                                     
Out[179]: numpy._globals._NoValueType
```

So that explains, in part, the `_NoValueType` reference in  the error.

What's your `scipy` version?

```
In [180]: import scipy                                                          
In [181]: scipy.__version__                                                     
Out[181]: '1.2.1'
```

I wonder if your `scipy.linalg.svd` is returning a `S` array that is an 'old' `ndarray`, and doesn't fully implement this `initial` parameter.  I can't explain why that could happen, but can't explain otherwise why the array `sum` is having problems with a `np._NoValue`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the `scipy` version . I had 1.1.0. Reinstalling `scipy`, `numpy` and `numpy-base` fixed the issue.